# Getting mail with following content by root automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using ubuntu 10.04. I've set mail server details in ssmtp and mentioned that path in sendmail_path of the `php.ini` file.

I'm receiving the following lines of content by mail

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

> '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol:
>   php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP
>   Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol:
>   php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0

What might be the reason?

Comment: Looks to me it has nothing to do with ssmtp and sendmail? I mean, they are the "reason" you get the mail in the end, but the reason the mail was send origionally is because there was an error. I presume you want the error fixed? or just the mail stopped?

Comment: I want to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the extension_dir is not set correctly in your php.ini file. If it's not then php will not be able to load the extensions set in the configuration.